# Multidimensional numpy.outer without flatten

Tags: numpy, matrix, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication

x is N by M matrix.

y is 1 by L vector.

I want to return "outer product" between x and y, let's call it z.

```
z[n,m,l] = x[n,m] * y[l]
```

I could probably do this using einsum.

```
np.einsum("ij,k->ijk", x[:, :, k], y[:, k])
```

or reshape afterwards.

```
 np.outer(x[:, :, k], y).reshape((x.shape[0],x.shape[1],y.shape[0]))
```

But I'm thinking of doing this in np.outer only or something seems simpler, memory efficient.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's one of those `numpy` "can't know unless you happen to know" bits: `np.outer` flattens multidimensional inputs while `np.multiply.outer` doesn't:

```
m,n,l = 3,4,5
x = np.arange(m*n).reshape(m,n)
y = np.arange(l)
np.multiply.outer(x,y).shape
# (3, 4, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code for `outer` is:

```
multiply(a.ravel()[:, newaxis], b.ravel()[newaxis, :], out)
```

As its docs says, it flattens (i.e. `ravel`).  If the arrays are already 1d, that expression could be written as

```
a[:,None] * b[None,:]
a[:,None] * b        # broadcasting auto adds the None to b
```

We could apply broadcasting rules to your (n,m)*(1,l):

```
In [2]: x = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4); y = np.array([[1,2]])                                                
In [3]: x.shape, y.shape                                                                                     
Out[3]: ((3, 4), (1, 2))
```

You want a (n,m,l), which a `(n,m,1) * (1,1,l)` achieves.  We need to add a trailing dimension to `x`.  The extra leading 1 on `y` is automatic:

```
In [4]: z = x[...,None]*y                                                                                    
In [5]: z.shape                                                                                              
Out[5]: (3, 4, 2)
In [6]: z                                                                                                    
Out[6]: 
array([[[ 0,  0],
        [ 1,  2],
        [ 2,  4],
        [ 3,  6]],

       [[ 4,  8],
        [ 5, 10],
        [ 6, 12],
        [ 7, 14]],

       [[ 8, 16],
        [ 9, 18],
        [10, 20],
        [11, 22]]])
```

Using `einsum`:

```
In [8]: np.einsum('nm,kl->nml', x, y).shape                                                                  
Out[8]: (3, 4, 2)
```

The fact that you approved:

```
In [9]: np.multiply.outer(x,y).shape                                                                         
Out[9]: (3, 4, 1, 2)
```

suggests `y` isn't really `(1,l)` but rather (l,)`.  Adjust for either is easy.

I don't think there's much difference in memory efficiency among these.  In this small example `In[4]` is fastest, but not by much.